# C function fread() does not read entire file

Tags: c, malloc

In C, I am reading the entire contents of the file Data_A into a buffer created with malloc().  The file contains 1000 random integers in the range 5 to 1000.

When I read the file, the newLen variable (see below) shows that the read size is 1001.  When I iterate over it as shown below, I get valid numbers (each number correctly corresponds to what's in the file), until it reaches 250 where it returns a negative number.  Obviously it read only 251 integers from a file of 1000 integers, but I don't know why.  Here's the code:

```
char FileA [] = "C:/C_Projects/Data_A";
int *buffer1 = NULL;
FILE *pRead;
FILE *fp = fopen(FileA, "rb");
FILE *ptr_test;

fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
long bufsize = ftell(fp);
buffer1 = malloc(bufsize + 1);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
int nums_to_read = bufsize / 4;
size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, 1, nums_to_read, fp);
buffer1[++newLen] = '\0';

fclose(fp);

// Iterate
int i;
int abc;
int bcd;

for (i = 0; i < bufsize / 4; i++)
{
    abc = buffer1[i];

    if (abc < 0)
    {
        bcd = 0;
    }
    if (i >= 200)
    {
        bcd = 0;
    }
}
```

As I said, all numbers in the file are positive numbers between 5 and 1000; there are no zeroes or negative numbers.  So I don't understand why it's not reading all 1000 integers.  The variable bufsize confirms that the buffer is 4000 bytes.

Any ideas will be most appreciated.

Comment: `nums_to_read = bufsize / 4`: Am I missing something or did you just define you just want to fill the first fourth?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. You might consider actually making a short complete example, headers, main, etc. What does the data in your file look like? How was the file created? Allocating an extra byte and null terminating a buffer of integers seems a little silly. As @MarcusMüller mentioned, you would need to use `sizeof(int)` as the size of an individual element in your fread call rather than 1 in order to read the right amount of data.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: the problem lies in the combination of that number with `fread`. `bufsize/4` is the number of elements but come `fread`, OP changed his mind and wants to read 1-byte elements.

Comment: @usr2564301 obviously, yes. I was assuming that was clear from the context.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: from the same context, it was obviously not that clear to OP :)

Comment: @usr2564301 yeah, that might very well be the case.

Comment: @Retired Ninja -- you are correct.  Changing the file read line to size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, sizeof(int), nums_to_read, fp); corrected the problem and now it reads the entire file.  Thank you very much.

Comment: `size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, 1, bufsize, fp);` or `size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, sizeof *buf, nums_to_read, fp);`

Comment: How is `(abc < 0)` ever true when *"the file contains 1000 random integers in the range 5 to 1000."*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has various problems and weaknesses, the biggest was a [scant](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scant)  read. [@Marcus Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290878/c-function-fread-does-not-read-entire-file/48291540#comment83566925_48290878) [@Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290878/c-function-fread-does-not-read-entire-file/48291540#comment83566937_48290878)
1 was too small an element size

```
// fread(buffer1, 1, nums_to_read, fp);
// read nums_to_read elements
// Each elements has the size of `sizeof buffer[0]`
fread(buffer1, sizeof buffer[0], nums_to_read, fp);
```

Other improvements in code.  `Handle_Error()` is some error handling code to be written.

```
char FileA [] = "C:/C_Projects/Data_A";
// FILE *pRead;  // not used here
FILE *fp = fopen(FileA, "rb");
if (fp == NULL) Handle_Error();
// FILE *ptr_test;  // not used here

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long bufsize = ftell(fp);
if (bufsize == -1) Handle_Error();

int *buffer1 = malloc(bufsize + sizeof *buffer1);
if (buffer1 == NULL) Handle_Error();

// fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
rewind(fp);  // rewind is sufficient and more clear

// int nums_to_read = bufsize / 4;
size_t nums_to_read = (size_t) bufsize / sizeof *buffer1;

size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, sizeof buffer[0], nums_to_read, fp);
if (newLen != nums_to_read) Handle_Error();

// buffer1[++newLen] = '\0';
buffer1[newLen] = 0;
fclose(fp);

int bcd = 1; // likely should have a default value
// Iterate
// for (int i = 0; i < (size_t) bufsize / 4; i++) {
for (size_t i = 0; i < newLen; i++) {
    int abc = buffer1[i];

    if (abc < 0) {
        bcd = 0;
    }
    if (i >= 200) {
        bcd = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only tweak would be `if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) == -1) { /* handle error */}`. Other than that, I still don't see how `if (abc < 0)` could ever be true with values of `5 - 1000`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True about `fseek()`, yet its failure rate is like `fclose()`.  Re: `if (abc < 0)` likely just placeholder code for a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in the final comment above, but to make this post appear as an answered question, I am posting this here too.  Changing the fread line to `size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, sizeof(int), nums_to_read, fp);` corrected the problem and now it reads the entire file.

Thanks very much to [@Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290878/c-function-fread-does-not-read-entire-file#comment83566937_48290878) and the others who replied to this question.

Comment: Code is still broken with `buffer1[++newLen] = '\0';`.  Suggest `buffer1[newLen] = '\0';`

Comment: @chux 1 -- it makes no difference; works just the same either way.

Comment: `buffer1[++newLen]` can cause _undefined behavior_ and so your results that way are moot.  Good code does not access outside the allocated memory: use `buffer1[newLen]`.  Review carefully what `buffer1[++newLen] = '\0';` attempts.  It is -off-by-1

Comment: On review, even `buffer1[newLen]` may be a problem as `malloc(bufsize + 1);` may be too small.  To append an `int` zero, code should use `malloc(bufsize + sizeof(int))`.  IAC, that appended zero, does not appear to be used in the following code so no need to allocate for it nor assign it.

Comment: @chux In this case it doesn't matter because I instruct it to iterate over the first 1000 elements.  However, for complete safety your solution is intuitively correct.  I changed those lines to:

buffer1 = malloc(bufsize + sizeof(int));
buffer1[newLen+1] = '\0';

Comment: Why the +1 in `buffer1[newLen+1] = '\0'`?  Certainly `buffer1[newLen] = '\0'` is what you want.  For simplicity, consider `bufsize == 0`,`sizeof(int)==4`.  `buffer1 = malloc(4); buffer1[1] = '\0';` accesses outside allocated memory.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers (the one that helped more, or yours if none of the others is acceptable for you) to clearly state that you need no longer help with this question.

Comment: All three had good ideas.  My own answer solved the problem, but Chux gave additional useful details, so I chose his as best.  Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

the error is here

```
int nums_to_read = bufsize / 4;
size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, 1, nums_to_read, fp);
```

the second param to fread is the size of the elements to read. the third is how many to read. It seems you intent is to read 4 bytes numbers (since you divieded the length by 4). So you should say

```
int nums_to_read = bufsize / 4;
size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, 4, nums_to_read, fp);
```

This skip over the whole issue of - are your ints 4 bytes. And is the file really raw 4 bytes ints.

Comment: that's right -- in my answer posted above we changed that line to size_t newLen = fread(buffer1, sizeof(int), nums_to_read, fp);