# fgets that doesn't stop at spaces or linebreaks

Tags: c, fgets, userspace

I'm writing a user space program and I want to send a text file content to the kernel module. The text file isnt to long so instead of sending line by line I rather send all the text in one string.

```
FILE *rules_text_file;
char *rules = (char *)malloc(sizeof(50*256*sizeof(char))); 
....
if (fgets(rules, 100, rules_text_file) == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
printf("%s\n",rules);  
          
fclose(rule_dev_file);
fclose(rules_text_file);
free(rules);
return 0;
```

I noticed that fget break at space and line break. Is there another function that reads text file and save it in a string I can use?

The text file len is below 50*256 char.

Comment: `fgets` normally stops at the end of the line.  But you're telling it to stop after 100 characters.  Traditionally you'd loop over the file, creating a buffer for each line and then store those buffers into an array.  But do you just want to read the entire file and not worry about line breaks?  If so, you need to determine the size of the file, allocate a buffer, and read it.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290878/c-function-fread-does-not-read-entire-file) and many others on how to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: If you don't care about lines, use `fread()` rather than `fgets()`.

Comment: `fgets()` doesn't stop at spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you are not regarding any line breaks or other breaks, so as comment says:

> If you don't care about lines, use `fread()` rather than `fgets()`.

The code is as follows:

```c
char *rules = malloc(sizeof(50*256*sizeof(char))); 
/* ... */
memset(rules, 0, 50 * 256);
errno = 0;
/* read one byte less to make string functions happy */
size_t len = fread(rules, 1, 50*256 - 1, rules_text_file)
if (errno) {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Zero is not the only error return from `fread`; if an error occurs or end-of-file is encountered, it returns a short count (a number less than the number of objects requested). And, unless OP’s use case is that the read must be all of the 50•256 bytes or nothing (e.g., they do not want to handle a case where the file contains only, say, 25•256 bytes, and that is normal and the program should continue), the return value must be saved in a variable and used to determine how much data was read. In that case, they probably also want `fread(rules, 1, 256*50,…)` so they get an exact byte count.

Comment: Is there one too many `sizeof`s in that `malloc`?

Answer (score 1):

The best `fgets()` is one you write yourself.  I too grew weary of `fgets()` limits and such.  For example, at one time I was reading *lots* of files and always had to add code to remove the newline ( '\n' ) character from the buffer after each read.

Finally, I wrote this code which stops reading at the newline ( like std lib `fgets()` ) -- but does *not* store the newline char into the buffer.

If you don't want this code to break/stop reading at the newline character, then just comment out the line below `done_reading = 1;` which appears at `switch()`  `case '\n':`.  Of course, you can edit this code endlessly to make it behave however you wish -- and that's the beauty of C and coding in general.

Best wishes and happy coding.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
char *myfgets(buffer, count, stream) - input string from a stream

Purpose: 
    Read a string from the input stream argument and store it in
    buffer. myfgets() reads characters from the current stream position to 
    and including the first newline character ('\n'), to the end of the 
    stream, or until the number of characters read is equal to count - 1, 
    whichever comes first. 

    The result stored in buffer is appended with a NUL ('\0') character. 
    The newline character('\n'), if read, is NOT included in the buffer.
    The carriage return('\r'), if read, is also NOT included in the buffer.

Entry:
       char *buffer- pointer to place to store bytes
       int count - max characters to place in buffer
       FILE *fp - stream to read from

Exit:
       returns buffer with text read from file.
       if count <= 0 return NULL
       returns NULL if error or end-of-file found immediately

*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char *myfgets (char *buff, int count, FILE *fp )
{
char *ptr = buff;
int ch, done_reading = 0; 

    if(!buff || !fp || count < 1)
        return NULL;

    while (count-- > 1 && !done_reading)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);

        switch(ch)
        {
            /* Carriage return: 0x0D   Linefeed: 0x0A
            ** In MSDOS/Windows each line ends with sequence 0D,0A (\r,\n); */
            case '\n':      /* Never accumulate linefeed into the buffer ... */
                done_reading = 1;  /* Comment out this line and reading will not stop here! */
            case '\r':      /* Never accumulate carriage return into the buffer.*/
            break;

            case EOF:
                if (ptr == buff)
                    return NULL;
                done_reading = 1;

            default:
               *ptr++ = (char) ch;
            break;
        }
    }
    *ptr = '\0'; /* cap it */
    return(buff);
}
```

Comment: Reading one character at a time is inefficient for OP’s request.

Comment: I agree that the user-selected fread() answer above is the better answer (not mine).  That said, to address Eric's kind comment -- aren't all the fread() implementations actually reading a byte-at-a-time internally?  This notion is supported [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590471/3130521).

Comment: Re “… aren't all the fread() implementations actually reading a byte-at-a-time internally?”: Certainly not. Off the cuff, an `fread` implementation would: Check error/EOF status. Select minimum of requested length and data currently in stream buffer. Copy that much from stream buffer to user buffer. If more needed, call OS to refill buffer and repeat previous. Return length read or EOF/error indication. The copy could be done with an inline `memcpy`, likely using either a hardware move-many-bytes instruction or various optimizations such as moving a whole register at a time…

Comment: … In contrast, an `fgetc` would repeat the error/EOF, length check (necessary even for one byte, as you cannot read one byte if there are zero available), copy, and return. And, if it is not inlined or implemented with a macro, the function call and return operations have to be performed as well.